# Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-bloc(8,2) on Fedora 25

Tags: linux-device-driver, nvidia, fedora-25

The error occur when I follow a  guide to install nVidia proprietary drivers on Fedora 25. 
This is link website:[enter link description here](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/)

I do step by step until I finish step 2.7 and reboot

Now I can not startup fedora 25
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fI2b.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that on step `2.6.2 Edit /etc/sysconfig/grub` you copied the example line verbatim instead of adapting it to your system:

```
## Example row ##
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau"
```

You should only append `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau` to end of the existing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”…”` line.

Comment: thank you for advice. I fixed my issue. I forgot to step 2.6.5 Generate initramfs "create new initramfs image" that for reason I Couldn't start fedora